# OpenAFS on OpenVZ guest

Tags: kernel, openvz, openafs

I'm trying to install and configure an OpenAFS server inside an OpenVZ container.
However, when running afs-newcell, it complains that the AFS client cannot be started. It says "AFS module /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-openvz-amd64/fs/openafs.o does not exist."

In the host, I installed openafs-modules-2.6.32-5-openvz-amd6 (from MIT). Doing lsmod | grep afs on host works, and show that openafs module is loaded. Doing the same in the guest doesn't show the module.

I understand that modprobe cannot be run inside a container for stability and security reason, but is there any way of "sharing" some module with a specified guest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to stop using `afs-newcell` and just configure the AFS server manually.

`afs-newcell` wants your server to also be an AFS client.  It's doing this because it's going to be helpful when setting up a brand new cell and create your `root.afs` and `root.cell` volumes and populate `root.afs` with the contents of your `CellServDB` file.  But all of that is to some extent optional, and more to the point, can be done from some other AFS client.  You don't need to do all of that inside your OpenVZ container, and probably don't want to go to the work of figuring out how to make `afs-newcell` believe that it's a client.

The only really tricky thing that `afs-newcell` does is to run `pt_util` to create the initial `ptserver` database.  I would just follow [the normal AFS server setup instructions](http://docs.openafs.org/QuickStartUnix/index.html) rather than trying to use the script.

Note that if this is a server for an existing cell, as opposed to setting up a brand new AFS cell, you don't want to be using `afs-newcell` at all.  It's only for setting up the first server in a completely new cell.

Comment: Hi, I've tagged your answer as accepted because it probably would have fixed my issue :). However, I cannot test it because I don't run this configuration anymore.